# WSO2 API Manager 1.6 HTTPS Transport does not expose an endpoint

Tags: java, web-services, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using WSO2 API Manager 1.6. I have a web service which runs on http. I'm going to expose the particular web service via API Manager as a https web service to the developer. Below is the endpoint for http web service via API Manager(HTTP is ticked in the Publisher under Transports).

```
http://api.myweb.com:8280/balance/1.0
```

But the problem is if I uptick HTTP in the Publisher under Transports and tick HTTPS my endpoint becomes as below which is not accessible. Base URL disappears.

```
/balance/1.0
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `api-manager.xml` transports must be specified correctly.

The system reads gateway endpoints from `api-manager.xml` file. When there are multiple gateway environments defined, it picks the gateway endpoint of the production environment. You can define both HTTP and HTTPS gateway endpoints as follows:

```
<GatewayEndpoint>http://${carbon.local.ip}:${http.nio.port},https://${carbon.local.ip}:${https.nio.port}</GatewayEndpoint>
```

If both types of endpoints are defined, the HTTPS endpoint will be picked as the server endpoint.